# Can't find standbydelayhigh and standbydelaylow on MacBook Pro 2021

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, mac, apple-silicon, monterey

When, on my MacBook Pro (M1 Pro) Monterey 12.1, I run

> sudo pmset -g

I get these current power settings:

```
System-wide power settings:
Currently in use:
 standby              1
 Sleep On Power Button 1
 SleepServices        0
 hibernatefile        /var/vm/sleepimage
 powernap             0
 networkoversleep     0
 disksleep            10
 sleep                1 (sleep prevented by powerd)
 hibernatemode        3
 ttyskeepawake        1
 displaysleep         15
 tcpkeepalive         0
 lowpowermode         0
 womp                 0
```

Where can I find the current values for standbydelayhigh or standbydelaylow?

Comment: What is in the power management log? That is, what do you get with `pmset -g log | grep HibernateStats`?  By the by, the sudo is not needed to read values or the log.

Comment: @Gilby by running this command I can see: "hibmode=3 standbydelaylow=0 standbydelayhigh=0", however the 0 values are wrong because previously I've changed those values by running "sudo pmset -a standbydelayhigh 3600" and "sudo pmset -a standbydelaylow 3600"

Comment: I know (from MacRumors) that hibernatemode was always 0 on M1 until macOS 11.3, but assumed it was all fixed at that point.  Seems that your MBP is ignoring your standbydelay setting. I have Intel Macs with modified standbydelayhigh/low, so will have to step back and hope someone with an M1 Mac can reproduce (or better fix) your issue. Sorry.

Comment: @Gilby the hibernatemode works well. I've tried to set it to value=25 and the waking up is significantly slower comparing to the default one (value=3). But standbydelay is indeed being ignored. Anyway, thanks for your effort :)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think M1 supports highstandbythreshold, standbydelaylow, standbydelayhigh. I'm on Monterey 12.4 with M1 Macbook Air.

My intent was to get my macbook M1 to go to hibernate after sleeping for X duration. But I have been unable to set these values.

hibernatemode 25 works, but will cause the macbook to immediately go into hibernate, which can be a nuisance when quick close and open of the M1 macbook lid is performed (e.g. moving from one sitting area to another, putting the laptop in the bag for a few seconds, etc.)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/322807)

Comment: This answer is an answer. The features the original poster is asking for don't seem to exist on Monterey. The only way to get hibernate on a portable M1 Mac is to switch to hibernatemode 25.

Comment: @Foliovision Even though it's impossible to prove a negative, the answer could nevertheless benefit from referencing a reliable source for the claim made in the first sentence.

Comment: ceevee has the computer in question and has tested it, as I have. I see ceevee doesn't have much reputation, but I do have some and have carefully and painstakingly tested my M1 Max and was unable to make standby, standbydelaylow, standbyhigh to actually do anything. Unless you have a reliable reference to standby functionality (light sleep going into hibernate), I'd suggest you and @agarza back off a bit.